# Always turn on SSH agent forwarding in ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible

Is it possible in Ansible (v2.9) to always do “ssh agent forwarding”? i.e. the `-A` option for ssh. In the inventory, for each host, I can add `ansible_ssh_extra_args="-A"` for each host, but I don't know what to put in `ansible.cfg` to apply by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to `group_vars/all.yml`.

This variable file is used for all hosts. It can be [overridden by variables with higher priority](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).